Extract values from string using regex
I am using this regex to extract 3 values from a string:
'Rgba\(\n.*\n.*?(?<digits0>\d{1,3},)\n.*?(?<digits1>\d{1,3},)\n.*?(?<digits2>\d{1,3},)\n.*\n.*\n.*

I'm using this to capture the first 3 values and comma for first 2 values from the following output:
'Rgba(
    [
        89,
        89,
        89,
        255,
    ],
)'

I am not sure how to do this properly with split() or some other method to extract the 3 values (I don't care if it's all 4 values for that matter).
I am doing a capture and then a format! to join them, so I can test it contains the 3 values.
Can someone help me simplify this at all?
My current attempt is:
With the input string of:
'Rgba(
    [
        89,
        89,
        89,
        255,
    ],
)'

let mut reg_test = Regex::new(r"'Rgba\(\n.*\n.*?(?<digits0>\d{1,3},)\n.*?(?<digits1>\d{1,3},)\n.*?(?<digits2>\d{1,3}),\n.*\n.*\n.*").unwrap();
let Some(caps) = reg_test.captures(&text_string) else {
                            println!("no match!");
                            return;
                        };
let joined_text = format!("{}{}{}", &caps["digits0"], &caps["digits1"], &caps["digits2"]).contains("0,0,0");
println!("Result: {}", joined_text);

Output is 89,89,89

try [^\d]*(\d+) https://regex101.com/r/k8bQXP/1

Do I understand correctly that the only problem here is that the Regex seems overly complicated to you?

As you are matching one occurrence of a pattern and then access groups, you cannot shorten it too much, Rgba\((?:\n.*?){2}(?<digits0>\d{1,3},)\n.*?(?<digits1>\d{1,3},)\n.*?(?<digits2>\d{1,3},) seems to work, and it is still long.

@Fildor - no it just seems that the way I am approaching it might not be the best. At the end of the day it works and does the job. I just thought there might be a better way of doing it that's all.

@AlexeyR. This certainly seems to match in the link provided, but it doesn't work when it's compiled I get:
caps: Captures(     {         0: 0..23/"'Rgba(\n    [\n        89",         1: 21..23/"89",     }, )


Split the string into individual lines using lines().
Filter each line to extract only numbers. use filter_map() to remove non-numeric lines (any chars like ',') & parse the numbers into u32.
Join the extracted values in the required format.
The revised code is:

fn extract_values(input: &str) -> Vec<u32> {
    input
        .lines()
        .filter_map(|line| {
            line.trim()
                .trim_end_matches(',')
                .parse::<u32>()
                .ok()
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"
        Rgba(
            [
                89,
                89,
                89,
                255,
            ],
        )
    "#;

    let values = extract_values(input);
    
    if values.len() >= 3 {
        let joined_text = format!("{},{},{}", values[0], values[1], values[2]);
        let contains_zeros = joined_text.contains("0,0,0");
        println!("Extracted values: {:?}", values);
        println!("Does it contain 0,0,0? {}", contains_zeros);
    } else {
        println!("Not enough values found");
    }
}


Thanks - this is really useful and gives me few ideas. zeros are valid numbers (0,0,0,255) is black for example, but that's easy enough to take out. Appreciate it thanks.
